# Cisco IP Phone detect incoming calls and caller info

Tags: c#, cisco

we use Cisco IP Phones in our company.
I need to create a windows service which detects incoming calls to a certain phone number (let say 911) and get caller's info.
My programming language would be C#.

Since I have no idea where to start, I don't have any code right now.

Comment: Google and Cisco websites are your friends then.

Answer (score 2):

IP Phones use a protocol called SIP - Session Initiation Protocol to advertise their presence and their IP address to a central registry. It works in a very similar fashion to a DNS. The phone says "Hi, I'm on 192.168.10.45 and my names are phone numbers 089981283 092349220 and 3482487243"

When another SIP enabled device (typically another phone or a call coming into your network via a SIP enabled phone exchange) wants to talk to your phone number it makes a call to the SIP registry, obtains the correct IP address and initiates the IP session with it. The nice thing is that the phone number could be any identifier - your name, your department name, or any other identifier. It doesnt even have to be unique - and thats how you get "group pickup".

Your problem is that you want to fool the SIP exchange into routing calls to your IP Phone to your PC instead, and vet the calls, before passing it onto the phone for normal handling. As you can see from my explanation, the IP Phone exists on the network as an independent Internet-of-things device and the phone would have to be equipped with a software API specifically to let you do what you want - so you are going to have to pull the docs on the Cisco phones and see if they do have an API you can use.

As to whether this can be done in C# then "yes". It has a comprehensive sockets handling layer for IP based comms and SIP is a very simple text based protocol over IP, so as long as the phone will allow you to take calls on its behalf and then forward the valid calls to it, then you can code a SIP compliant service in C# and achieve your aim. Try googling "C# SIP" and you will find at least this example C# implementation https://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/

Comment: Actually, Cisco phones in most cases use SCCP not SIP.